# Правильное использование Yandex Disk API Client for .NET C#

Tags: c#, yandex-disk

Хочу написать приложение для загрузки файлов на Яндекс.Диск с помощью C#. В Nuget нашел такую библиотеку: https://github.com/raidenyn/yandexdisk.client
Установил ее, а также дополнительные библиотеки, которые для этого требовались.
Кинул на форму кнопку и написал следующий код

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(UploadSample);
    }

    async Task UploadSample()
    {
        //You should have oauth token from Yandex Passport.
        //See https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/
        string oauthToken = "Здесь мой токен";

        // Create a client instance
        IDiskApi diskApi = new DiskHttpApi(oauthToken);

        //Upload file from local
        await diskApi.Files.UploadFileAsync(path: "1.txt",
                                            overwrite: false,
                                            localFile: @"D:\1.txt",
                                            cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

Но возникла парочка вопросов:

1) Токен - это то, что указано в строке https://oauth.yandex.ru/client/****************************** и заменено на звездочки?

2)Объясните, пожалуйста, почему эту функцию необходимо выполнять таким вот образом, как я написал в обработчике кнопки. Первоначальное я просто писал `UploadSample();`, но студия предложила вариант с `await Task.Run`.

3)Как избавиться от ошибки "Программа не содержит статического метода "Main", подходящего для точки входа"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Токен** - [читаем документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/).
2. **async/await** - Все методы, которые могут долго обрабатываться (запрос к серверу например), лучше использовать асинхронно. Это позволит выполнять другие действия и не ждать выполнения текущего.
3. **Main** - Вы удалили скорей всего стартовый метод. Создайте новое приложение и посмотрите, как выглядит внутри код. Обычно его вид следующий:

Console App:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    /* */
}
```

WinForms App:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: а разве в win forms приложении может быть метод Main?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров В любом приложение есть входная точка. В WinForms она находится в файле Program.cs. Дополнил ответ его изначального вида.

Comment: А, вот, вижу, что отсутствует файл Program.cs. Только я его не трогал...  Может ошибка "обнаружены неразрешимые конфликты между различными версиями одной и той же зависимой сборки.  Эти конфликты перечислены в журнале сборки, если выбран подробный уровень детализации журнала" как-то с этим связана?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Такая ошибка обычно связана с пакетами, не уверен по поводу самого приложения. На вашем месте я бы создал чистый проект и с ним работал бы.

Comment: да, создание нового приложения помогло, спасибо. Но теперь при нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Это может быть связано с токеном приложения? Токен я пытаюсь получать с помощью Nemiro.OAuth, но, похоже, делаю это не так, как надо, раз не работает. Пример: https://pastebin.com/gBzESVrs

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Newtonsoft.Json - сторонняя библиотека, находится в NuGet (Пкм по проекту - Менеджер NuGet пакетов - В поиск Newtonsoft.Json и устанавливаете)

Comment: Он, как оказывается, уже был установлен. Только его надо было обновить до текущей версии, чтобы все заработало. Спасибо) Теперь явно видно ошибку авторизации, что уже хорошо. Можете глянуть тот код получения токена, который я скинул выше?

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Ну ошибки авторизации бывают разные. Проверьте правильность своего токена, вы его должны были получить при регистрации приложения по ссылке из ответа.